# significance of (void*) -1

Tags: c, pointers, memory, system-calls

I was looking at the documentation of `sbrk` system call and found [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk):

> On success, `sbrk()` returns the previous program break.  (If the break was increased, then this value is a pointer to the start of the newly allocated memory).  On error, `(void *) -1` is returned, and `errno` is set to `ENOMEM`.

Now,

1. What's the significance of `(void *) -1`?
2. What is the exact memory address it points to? (if it does at all)
3. How is it guaranteed that `(void *) -1` is not a valid address
   that can be returned by `sbrk()` on success?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(void *) -1 == (size_t) -1
```

It's `0xFFFFFFFF` on 32 bit machine and `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on 64 bit machine, an invalid address that is supposed to be bigger than any other address.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound totally noob, but how is `(void *) -1` equal to  `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: @tomol, read up on [2s complement](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html)

Comment: @tomol , think of it in the other direction, how much is `0xFFFFFFFF + 1`? it's `0`!... Once the variable experiences overflow due to it's bitsize limits, interesting things can happen ;-)

Comment: @Matt you're wrong. C standard doesn't say anything about 2s complement.

Comment: @tomol, and yet a compiled `c` program doesn't run in a vacuum. Something like the Llinux kernel which is architecture aware, can safely say that `0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1`

Comment: @tomol The C standard doesn't say anything about `sbrk` either. This whole thing is inherently implementation specific.

Comment: I would challenge the term "invalid" - It is a perfectly valid address addressing the highest addressable byte in the address space. It is, however, a non-sensible address to be returned by `sbrk()` and thus can be used to signal failure.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What's the significance of `(void *) -1`?

It's simply a sentinel value that `sbrk()` would be incapable of returning in a successful case.

> 2. What is the exact memory address it points to? (if it does at all)

It's not expected to be a valid address, and the specific value is not relevant.

> 3. How is it guaranteed that `(void *) -1` is not a valid address that can be returned by `sbrk()` on success?

It perhaps seems like circular reasoning, but it's guaranteed because `sbrk()` guarantees it as part of its contract. (For example, `sbrk()` could check whether it *would* return that value if successful; if so, it instead could do nothing and report failure.)

In practice, `(void*) -1` on most modern machines is going to be `0xFF...FF`, which would be the highest possible address, and that's simply something that's unlikely to be valid.

Comment: Furthermore even if `0xFF..FF` was a valid address, as far as systems that have the `sbrk` syscall are concerned this is an address in kernel space, which is not reachable while in user mode. Technically `sbrk` could return *any* address in kernel space to user mode code to indicate an error.